# PHP: imagepng() creates broken image

Tags: php, image, png

I have a problem creating a thumnail of a PNG image.

This works:

```
    $src = imagecreatefromjpeg("http://www.gaze.se/".$folder.$filename);
    $rootfolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ;
    $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($targ_w, $targ_h);
    imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],$targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);
    imagejpeg($tmp, $rootfolder.$folder.'thumb_'.$filename,100);

    imagedestroy($tmp);
    imagedestroy($src);
```

Then I change the two jpeg functions to png, like this:

```
    $src = imagecreatefrompng("http://www.gaze.se/".$folder.$filename);
    $rootfolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ;
    $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($targ_w, $targ_h);
    imagecopyresampled($tmp, $src, 0,0,$_POST['x'],$_POST['y'],$targ_w,$targ_h,$_POST['w'],$_POST['h']);
    imagepng($tmp, $rootfolder.$folder.'thumb_'.$filename,100);

    imagedestroy($tmp);
    imagedestroy($src);
```

But then the image is broken, this message shows when i try to open it:

[image: Error message]

Any ideas of how to solve this?

Comment: Almost all GD functions return `false` upon failure, so you should check the return values of `imagecreatefrompng`, etc. to see where it goes wrong exactly.

Comment: Where's your header Content-type line?

Comment: @popnoodles That's not necessary when you save the image to a file.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't read it properly

Answer (score 8):

Check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php. The $quality parameter should be 0 to 9 for PNG files. And as @jeroen said, you should definitely check the return values.

Comment: You're the king